# Editar resultado de consulta laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

como podria modificar el resultado de esta consulta:

```
 $propiedad=ModeloCondominios::where('id','=',Crypt::decryptString($request->unidad))->first();
    return $propiedad->unidades;
```

La cual devuelve lo siguiente :

```
[{"id":2,"nombre":"CASA 1","codigo":"A95654F","propiedad_horizontal":1,"tipo_unidad":2,"created_at":"2021-11-28T16:23:03.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-11-28T16:23:03.000000Z"},{"id":3,"nombre":"DEPARTAMENTO 88","codigo":"A95654R","propiedad_horizontal":1,"tipo_unidad":1,"created_at":"2021-11-30T22:15:41.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-11-30T22:15:41.000000Z"}]
```

Quiero cifrar con el id con Crypt::encryptString, he tratado asi:

```
$propiedad->unidades[0]['id']=Crypt::encryptString($propiedad->unidades[0]['id']);
```

Pero a la hora de mostrar  $propiedad->unidades[0]['id'] me da solo como resultado "CERO" en numero,me asegure de que $propiedad->unidades[0]['id'] si contenga un numero antes de que se cifre.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

puedes crear un [accesor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) en el modelo `ModeloCondominios` de la siguiente manera

```
public function getIdAttribute($id)
{
    return Crypt::encryptString($id);
}
```

que es lo que hace esto, pues getIdAttribute obtiene el atributo id, luego retorna la encryptacion de este valor en este caso $id, cada vez que llames a `ModeloCondominios` este ya tendra encryptado el id.